# Does adding in line breaks affect SEO?

Tags: seo, content

If I put line breaks in a paragraph will that affect SEO?

E.g. If I did this:

> Fruitcake biscuit jelly beans cupcake
> sugar plum toffee liquorice. Cookie
> chocolate bar topping donut sesame
> snaps chocolate bar toffee chocolate.
> Macaroon chocolate cake tiramisu carrot
> cake pudding tiramisu chocolate sugar
> plum sesame snaps.

Instead of leaving the paragraph like this:

> Fruitcake biscuit jelly beans cupcake sugar plum toffee liquorice. Cookie chocolate bar topping donut sesame snaps chocolate bar toffee chocolate. Macaroon chocolate cake tiramisu carrot cake pudding tiramisu chocolate sugar plum sesame snaps.

Would this cause a problem with SEO?

Comment: I vote to reopen as the linked page is from 2011.     I do put to you that in 2022, maybe you should not be using linebreaks like this, and you should be designing responsive pages - possibly also encapsulating the text in a div or equivalent and sizing the div.

Comment: Given the answer to that question is that search engines can handle the whitespaces without problem, and that answer is still relevant and correct, I think the duplicate flag can stand.

Comment: @davidgo unfortunately the platform I'm using doesn't allow this